# Failed to parse SourceMap: angular-route.min.js.map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js

I am building Angular / Rails app now. 
For the purpose of routing, I'm using angular-route. 
I have added angular-route folder under node_modules folder like following:
[image]

All of sudden, my app started complaining about failed to parse sourcemap when it is in debugger mode like following `Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:3000/angular-route.min.js.map`. I did not change anything and even reinstalled npm module again but no luck. and the web app is not loaded at all.

I found from the that error is thrown because there is no `.map` file but it does exist in my folder as you can see. Should I not ust minified javascript?

And i confirm that this error is thrown and my app is not working only in Chrome. It works fine in Safari.